# Is there any way to use comma for java jsonpath concat function?

Tags: java, jsonpath

When we are trying to concat with a comma the character is getting ignored.

For example, my JSON data is

```
{ min: 5, max: 10, avg: 7 }
```

and JSONPath is

```
concat($.min, ",", $.max)
```

The expected result is `"5,10"` but the result returned is `"510"`

Tried with an underscore and it is working fine, but not working for comma.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Not sure why it doesn’t work, but perhaps you can replace the comma for a Unicode character. This works for me: `$.concat($.min,"\u002C",$.max)`.

Comment: Thanks @EdwinDalorzo for the information. Yes this unicode trick is working. In my application (android) the json path is a user configurable and I want to keep as simple as possible. I think this is a bug from library and it should be fixed.